How to receive IDs of all grouped photos in Telegram?
I'm writing a bot that saves user's notes. I'm facing a problem with adding the ability to receive attached grouped photos (files, videos, etc.). How can I get the IDs of all photos in a single message? I know about media_group_id, but I don't know how to get the photo IDs from it :( I'm writing in Python, using the pyTelegramBotAPI library.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
